# MS Access Average or Sum

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two columns of data that I need the average OR if one of the cells have a zero then just take the non zero value.

```
SELECT ID, IIF((A+B)=A, A,  IIF((A+B)=B, B, (A+B)/2)) AS AVE_AB <br/>
FROM Data;
```

Is there a way to make this code more efficient? I have another 25 variables to do this to, and would like to make my code more efficient and shorter if possible.

Comment: What version of Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building an Access Query that needs even slightly complex expression logic, and have to reuse that logic for many pairs of columns, you are better off creating a custom VBA function (also called a User Defined Function, or UDF) to do this work.  For your example, it's not hard; and this approach has several advantages, the most important of which are:

- clearer, cleaner code in SQL View
- reduced likelihood of errors due to typos that are hard to notice within repetitive text
- the workhorse code only appears once, so if you want to update it for performance or modify it for a different purpose, you only need to make your changes in a single place

Following the example of Excel's =AverageIF() function (which Access does not have built-in), you could create a new Module in Visual Basic along the lines of:

```
Public Function AverageIFNotZero(columnA, columnB)

    If columnA = 0 Then
        AverageIFNotZero = columnB
    Else
        If columnB = 0 Then
            AverageIFNotZero = columnA
        Else
            AverageIFNotZero = (columnA + columnB) / 2
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Then, you can reuse it easily in Query Designer or SQL View like this:

```
SELECT ID, AverageIFNotZero(A,B) AS AVE_AB, AverageIFNotZero(C,D) AS AVE_CD FROM Data;
```

If you have never worked with VBA before, here are the steps for setting this simple example up in Access 2013:

1. Select *Database Tools* from the ribbon menu, then under *Macro*,
   select *Visual Basic*. The editor (Microsoft Visual Basic for
   Applications) will open.
2. In the Project pane, there will be a node with the name of your database.  Right click that node and select Insert > Module.
3. A code window will appear with one or two lines of automatically generated code, something like: `Option Compare Database`, and/or `Option Explicit`.  Click beneath the code you see, and either type or paste
   everything from the code sample above that begins with `Public Function`.
4. Close the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window. The function should now be available for use in Query Designer or SQL View.
5. When closing the database, you will be asked to save your new module, and provide a name for it, just like you would for a new table or query.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know why after i save it and try to run the function it gives me an alert saying, "Undefined Function 'AverageIFNotZero' in Expresion" ? It runs fine before I save the function, but once it's saved I get this alert for some reason.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error unless I deliberately misspell the function name in either VBA or the query.  As long as they match (it's not even case sensitive) it seems to work fine for me, even after I save and reopen the database.  If you are still having trouble after saving, then please provide some more details about the version of Access you are using, and the exact names you are using for the UDF and the Module the UDF is in.  Then I can take another look.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT ID, IIF ((A*B) = 0, abs(A-B), (A+B)/2)) as AVE_AB
FROM Data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *Sgn*:

```
SELECT ID, (A + B) / (Sgn(A) + Sgn(B)) AS AVE_AB
FROM Data;
```

If A and/or B can be negative, apply *Abs*:

```
SELECT ID, (A + B) / (Abs(Sgn(A)) + Abs(Sgn(B))) AS AVE_AB
FROM Data;
```

It's not shorter, but A and B only need to be replaced twice contrary to five times as in your original code when you copy-paste for the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

A `SWITCH` function might help you. It's a bit more concise, but with a lot of logic to pass it may not get any easier to type. You can [find more info here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php)

```
SELECT ID,
       SWITCH(A+B=A,A,
              A+B=B,B,
              1=1,(A+B)/2) AS AVE_AB
FROM Data
```